# Drawable Layer always top

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, drawable

I don't know whether am wrong or not. I just want to add a box to my EmptyActivity in android studio. I create a resource file and access it from the Activity.xml file. But I found it always layered on top of any ImageView component.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmuxh.png)

Resouce file
page_select_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="@color/white" />
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />

</shape>
```

ActivityMain.xml

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/page_select_bar"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="777dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/page_select_bar"
        tools:targetApi="lollipop" />
```

am I missing anything? I'm new to android :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
<stroke android:color="@color/Black" android:width="2sp"/>
```

to your drawable inside `<shape>`

and use it as background

Comment: doesn't work, added an image for more info. I think Its a simple mistake.

Comment: Okay, finally I figure out my mistake, It was with the 'Elevation' when I remove it, all clear